# Functions and infinite loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The code below should create a function to calculate and return the sum of all of the even numbers from 0 to the passed number being 10(inclusive) using a while loop. But instead, it just creates an infinite loop and I don't know why.

```
def function(lex):
zero = 0 
while zero <= lex:
    while lex % 2 == 0:
        print(lex)
        zero = zero + 1
    while lex % 2 =! 0:
        zero = zero + 1
return sum
```

print(function(10))

Comment: Both inner while-loops have a condition based on the value of "lex" but don't modify it.

Comment: Besides the logic problem, your *indentation* needs to be fixed.  And don't use Python built-in *sum* as your variable.

Comment: And I suppose your inner `while`s should be `if`s (and you need only one of them)

Comment: After you read and fixed (based on the prev. comments), you could try - ```def sum_even(n):
    return sum(x for x in range(n+1) if x & 1)```

Comment: `!=`, not `=!`.

Comment: You don't need to test (or even generate) the odd numbers. `range(0, n+1, 2)`.

Comment: Nor do you  actually have to sum them; the sum is simply twice the sum of of the first `n//2` integers, which has a closed form. (e.g., `0 + 2 + 4 + 6 == 2*(0 + 1 + 2 + 3)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change the second and third while loops and replace them with an if statement that checks whether the number is even or odd.

Maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
def function(lex):
  sum = 0
  while 0 <= lex:
    if lex%2 == 0:
      print(lex)
      sum = sum + lex
    lex = lex-1
  return sum
```

And then you can call the function `print(function(10))`